# The project is using an incompatible version (AGP 8.2.0-alpha10) of the Android Gradle plugin. Latest supported version is AGP 8.0.2

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a android project that I downloaded from github, but I keep getting this error, I cant find where to download the plugin, only the reference, but it does not works...

This is the error I am getting:

The project is using an incompatible version (AGP 8.2.0-alpha10) of the Android Gradle plugin. Latest supported version is AGP 8.0.2

This is my build.gradle

```
/ Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.0-alpha10'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.2.0-alpha10' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.2.0-alpha10' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.0' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization' version '1.6.21'
}

tasks.register('clean') {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your Android Studio to the latest canary release or just change config for the compatible Gradle plugin.

Comment: could you provide more detail to this answer?

Comment: See https://developer.android.com/build/releases/gradle-plugin#compatibility

Answer (score 0):

I give an example of how to solve this problem:

in my incompatible-version-agp-8-1-0 and latest supported 8.0.2

so in `build.gradle`, app level.  commenting below lines

```
id 'com.android.application' version '8.1.0' apply false
id 'com.android.library' version '8.1.0' apply false
```

and adding below lines:

```
id 'com.android.application' version '8.0.2' apply false
id 'com.android.library' version '8.0.2' apply false
```